# JAX-RPC ServiceLifecycle not calling init

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, websphere, jax-rpc

I have a web project that uses JAX-RPC using SOAP requests and I can't modify it too much. This project is a bit outdated compared to another similar project we are currently maintaining.

I have been trying to get the IP address via the request headers like in our main project by implementing `javax.xml.rpc.server.ServiceLifecycle` in my Service Endpoint implementation class. According to [this tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-detect-ip-address-client-jax-rpc-webservice) I should be able to obtain the `ServletEndpointContext` via de init method:

```java
public class WebServiceImpl implements ServiceLifecycle {
    @Override
    public void init(Object context) throws ServiceException {
        System.out.println("Initializing...");
        ServletEndpointContext ctx = (ServletEndpointContext) context;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy(){
        // TODO
    }
}
```

However, it seems that the `init` method is never called and thus I am unable to get the IP from the header.

I have checked against our main project that also uses JAX-RPC and they are almost identical, the only difference being that the main project uses Spring and the Service Endpoint class extends from Spring's `ServletEndpointSupport` whilst implementing `ServiceLifecycle`.

Is there a certain configuration I need to have in order for this to work?

I have tried using a filter like stated in the tutorial and it seems to be working, however I need to be able to send that IP to my class and not just print it.

### Other Details:

- The project is built on WebSphere 7 but runs on a WebSphere 8.5 server
- Using Java 6